# How to filter rows containing a string pattern from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume we have a data frame in Python Pandas that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ids': [u'aball', u'bball', u'cnut', u'fball']})
```

Or, in table form:

```
ids    vals
aball   1
bball   2
cnut    3
fball   4
```

How do I filter rows which contain the key word "ball?" For example, the output should be:

```
ids    vals
aball   1
bball   2
fball   4
```

Answer (score 547, accepted):

```
In [3]: df[df['ids'].str.contains("ball")]
Out[3]:
     ids  vals
0  aball     1
1  bball     2
3  fball     4
```

Comment: How would you invert this to find all the rows that did not contain the string?

Comment: @user4896331 - `df[~df['ids'].str.contains("ball")]`,  `~` negates the condition

Comment: If it was a specific word, to negate, could you also use: df = df[df.id != "ball"]

Comment: @Brian - Yes, in the above df you can try `df = df[df.ids != "aball"]` to see it in action.

Comment: @Amit: I need to access columns by id instead of name. However trying str gives me an error [AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'] Does new pandas not support it or is it because of number based access?

Comment: never mind. I was using [[]]. After using [] it works.

Comment: @Amit, what if i have a list of strings that partially matches with column values. I want to extract all those rows.  For example, rows partially matchin "ball", and rows partially matching "bat" etc?

Comment: To search for dot `.` don't forget to escape it `df[df['ids'].str.contains("\.")]`

Comment: Guys, is it possible to write this with query?

Comment: I'm using `str.contains("'ball | bat | cat | man")` to filter using multiple keywords., which works fine. Is it possible  to print which row matched which keyword?

Answer (score 175):

```
df[df['ids'].str.contains('ball', na = False)] # valid for (at least) pandas version 0.17.1
```

Step-by-step explanation (from inner to outer):

- `df['ids']` selects the `ids` column of the data frame (technically, the object `df['ids']` is of type `pandas.Series`)
- `df['ids'].str` allows us to apply vectorized string methods (e.g., `lower`, `contains`) to the Series
- `df['ids'].str.contains('ball')` checks *each* element of the Series as to whether the element value has the string 'ball' as a substring. The result is a Series of Booleans indicating `True` or `False` about the existence of a 'ball' substring.
- `df[df['ids'].str.contains('ball')]` applies the Boolean 'mask' to the dataframe and returns a view containing appropriate records.
- `na = False` removes NA / NaN values from consideration; otherwise a ValueError may be returned.

Comment: Could you explain what that code is doing and how it works, please?

Comment: How to work with partial match and grab the remaining string with the partial match `'#':str` something like this?

Comment: Absolutely love it when someone does a step-by-step explanation. It really helps with comprehension!

Comment: And if you substitute `'ball'` with `'|'.join(list_of_balls)` one can apply a list of strings to the search. While the `'|'.join(list_of_balls)` creates a RegEx with OR to search for vaild strings

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, would you care to explain how the code shall change if I want to filter the rows with the exact value that I want instead of containing it? Thanks

Comment: Note that you can make the filter case insensitive adding `case=False`, reuslting in `df[df['ids'].str.contains('ball', case=False,na = False)]`

Comment: @Antonio thanks for that, `df[df['ids'].str.lower().contains('ball')]` throws an error

Comment: @TimStack, The reference is in the following link. Please, let me know what error do you get? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: `lower()` throws the error (`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'`). This does not matter however as you pointed out that `case=False` can be used instead

Comment: While for the specific case of ignoring case it's better to use the built-in way to do it through `case=False`, not that in general you _can_ chain operations like this, but you need to call the `str` attribute every time you do: `df.ids.str.lower().str.contains('ball')`

Answer (score 34):

```
>>> mask = df['ids'].str.contains('ball')    
>>> mask
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: ids, dtype: bool

>>> df[mask]
     ids  vals
0  aball     1
1  bball     2
3  fball     4
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to set the column you filter on as a new index, you could also consider to use [`.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html); if you want to keep it as a separate column then `str.contains` is the way to go.

Let's say you have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'ids': [u'aball', u'bball', u'cnut', u'fball', 'ballxyz']})

       ids  vals
0    aball     1
1    bball     2
2     cnut     3
3    fball     4
4  ballxyz     5
```

and your plan is to filter all rows in which `ids` contains `ball` AND set `ids` as new index, you can do

```
df.set_index('ids').filter(like='ball', axis=0)
```

which gives

```
         vals
ids          
aball       1
bball       2
fball       4
ballxyz     5
```

But `filter` also allows you to pass a regex, so you could also filter only those rows where the column entry ends with `ball`. In this case you use

```
df.set_index('ids').filter(regex='ball$', axis=0)

       vals
ids        
aball     1
bball     2
fball     4
```

Note that now the entry with `ballxyz` is not included as it starts with `ball` and does not end with it.

If you want to get all entries that start with `ball` you can simple use

```
df.set_index('ids').filter(regex='^ball', axis=0)
```

yielding

```
         vals
ids          
ballxyz     5
```

The same works with columns; all you then need to change is the `axis=0` part. If you filter based on columns, it would be `axis=1`.

Comment: Just saw your post as I was looking for a similar solution. I used the filter method you mentioned but failed to get desired results. The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52321121/pandas-failed-to-filter-rows-containing-a-specific-value-in-the-index-column-af/52321165?noredirect=1#comment91590757_52321165) Would you mind taking a look nad see if there's anything wrong with my code/method? IMO it shall be super simple albeit my being unable to make it work.

Comment: @BowenLiu: I added an answer there, please check whether that works for you.

Comment: Just got on my laptop for the night. Will do that real soon, thank you so much.

Comment: Note that contains also works with regex, the wording in this answer is a tiny bit misleading in that regard.