# Filtering DataFrame by list of substrings

Tags: pandas

Building off this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27975230), is there a way to filter a Pandas dataframe by a list of substrings?

Say I want to find all rows where df['menu_item'] contains `fresh` or `spaghetti`

Without something like this:

`df[df['menu_item'].str.contains('fresh') | (df['menu_item'].str.contains('spaghetti')]`

Comment: Would you consider using a custom function with a map ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method you're using accepts regex, so use the regex `|` as or:

```
df[df['menu_item'].str.contains('fresh|spaghetti')]
```

Example Input:

```
          menu_item
0        fresh fish
1      fresher fish
2           lasagna
3     spaghetti o's
4  something edible
```

Example Output:

```
       menu_item
0     fresh fish
1   fresher fish
3  spaghetti o's
```

Comment: winner winner spaghetti dinner

Comment: Cool solution :-)

Comment: Can it be used for a list where substrings are members of the list?