# Get rows in numpy array where column contains string

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array with 4 columns.  The first column is text.

I want to retrieve every row in the array where the first column contains a substring.

Example: if the string I'm searching for is "table", find and return all rows in the numpy array whose first column contains "table."

I've tried the following:

```
rows = nparray[searchString in nparray[:,0]]
```

but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Is pandas available? Because if it is this is easy.

Comment: The array I'm using is literally a pandas dataframe derived from as_matrix(), so it's very much available.  What did I miss?

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas#17071908.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a pandas DataFrame `df`, this will return all rows where `searchString` is a substring of the value in the column `column`:

```
searchString = "table"

df.loc[df['column'].str.contains(searchString, regex=False)]
```

Comment: Yep, after Paula Thomas led me down the pandas track, I came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975069/how-to-filter-rows-containing-a-string-pattern-from-a-pandas-dataframe/27975191, which is the same thing.  Thanks!

Comment: Add `regex=False` for a trivial speed-up.