# Failed to filter rows containing a specific value in the index column after resetting index

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I'm organizing data of a number of plans, which contains the information of the phase of the plan, P(Preliminary) or F(Final). I'm using the methods shown in the [examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) in the pandas documentation.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('FilePath', sheetname = 'ForFilter')
df1


landuse_SUB_ID  TYPE    RECD_DATE   PHASE   LAND_USE    CPACTIONDA
0   24  1   2000-04-07  P   ROW 2000-05-04
1   24  1   2000-04-07  P   NONE    2000-05-04
2   25  1   2000-08-10  P   COMM    2000-09-08
3   34  1   2000-04-14  F   REC 2000-04-14
4   34  1   2000-04-14  F   SFD 2000-04-14
5   35  1   2000-01-20  P   NONE    2000-02-02
6   42  1   2000-04-04  P   SFD 2000-05-01
7   42  1   2000-12-06  P   SFD 2001-01-03
8   43  1   2000-09-07  P   NONE    2000-09-21
9   51  1   2000-11-10  P   NONE    2000-11-28
10  53  1   2000-02-22  F   SFD 2000-02-22
```

After playing with the methods in the example (using `like` and `regex`), it seems to me that these methods can only filter the values in the index column. Therefore I changed the index:

```
df1_filter1 = df1.set_index('PHASE')


landuse_SUB_ID  TYPE    RECD_DATE   LAND_USE    CPACTIONDA
PHASE                   
P   24  1   2000-04-07  ROW 2000-05-04
P   24  1   2000-04-07  NONE    2000-05-04
P   25  1   2000-08-10  COMM    2000-09-08
F   34  1   2000-04-14  REC 2000-04-14
F   34  1   2000-04-14  SFD 2000-04-14
P   35  1   2000-01-20  NONE    2000-02-02
P   42  1   2000-04-04  SFD 2000-05-01
P   42  1   2000-12-06  SFD 2001-01-03
P   43  1   2000-09-07  NONE    2000-09-21
P   51  1   2000-11-10  NONE    2000-11-28
F   53  1   2000-02-22  SFD 2000-02-22
```

Now the data frame is using `Phase` as index, I used the `like` method to filter `df1_filter1`:

```
df1_filter1.filter(like = 'F', axis = 0)
```

I get the error

> "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

This seems like a really simple operation to me, so I'm just wondering what I did wrong to have caused this error. And what shall be the best method (fewest steps and cleanest code) for my question.

Comment: I am not able to recreate this problem. When I run your code, I get a filtered dataframe with the 3 rows indexed by F

Comment: @Andrew That's ridiculous then. I will try it again. May I ask you about the methods used in the filter documentation please? Does `like = ABC` filter rows with value of just `ABC` or contain `ABC`? And does `regex = 'e$'` mean filtering the rows ending in `e`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, for this task, `filter` is not required. In [@Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52321165/1534017) `loc` is used. As an alternative, you could also use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1.query('PHASE == "F"')

    landuse_SUB_ID  TYPE   RECD_DATE PHASE LAND_USE  CPACTIONDA
3               34     1  2000-04-14     F      REC  2000-04-14
4               34     1  2000-04-14     F      SFD  2000-04-14
10              53     1  2000-02-22     F      SFD  2000-02-22
```

`filter` works fine for me too:

```
df1_filter1 = df1.set_index('PHASE')
df1_filter1.filter(like='F', axis=0)

       landuse_SUB_ID  TYPE   RECD_DATE LAND_USE  CPACTIONDA
PHASE                                                       
F                  34     1  2000-04-14      REC  2000-04-14
F                  34     1  2000-04-14      SFD  2000-04-14
F                  53     1  2000-02-22      SFD  2000-02-22
```

Regarding your question about the use of `regex`:

```
df2 = df1.set_index('LAND_USE')
df2.filter(regex="E$", axis=0)

          landuse_SUB_ID  TYPE   RECD_DATE PHASE  CPACTIONDA
LAND_USE                                                    
NONE                  24     1  2000-04-07     P  2000-05-04
NONE                  35     1  2000-01-20     P  2000-02-02
NONE                  43     1  2000-09-07     P  2000-09-21
NONE                  51     1  2000-11-10     P  2000-11-28
```

Here you filter  all rows that end with an `E`.

The same you could achieve by e.g. doing:

```
df1[df1['LAND_USE'].str.endswith('E')]

   landuse_SUB_ID  TYPE   RECD_DATE PHASE LAND_USE  CPACTIONDA
1              24     1  2000-04-07     P     NONE  2000-05-04
5              35     1  2000-01-20     P     NONE  2000-02-02
8              43     1  2000-09-07     P     NONE  2000-09-21
9              51     1  2000-11-10     P     NONE  2000-11-28
```

The problem with `filter` here is that you then create an index with non-unique values which is usually a bad idea. So, I would go with `.loc` or `.query`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I couldn't possibly imagine a better answer than this. It seems to me that query is the best way for the specific purpose I presented in the question as it has the shortest/cleanest code. And somehow on my home laptop `filter` is working. If I may ask one more question which I just thought of as I'm still learning what pandas can do: how to filter/query columns based on certain string that the column names contain? Like for instance, I want to see all the column with names of "...date". Thanks again

Comment: @BowenLiu: Glad I could help. You can use `filter` also for the column names; for your example `df.filter(regex="date$")` should work (gets all columns that end with `date`).

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to find more to peruse about how to use `regex` and `like`  in pandas filter but yet to have any luck. Do you have any link to share? I'm under the impression that `like` means contain instead of `==`. Am I right on that? Thanks again.

Comment: @BowenLiu: The examples in the documentation are quite instructive I think. I recommend to create a toy example and just explore the different options by playing around. If you then observe unexpected behavior, you can open a new question :)

Answer (score 4):

`filter` may intuitively feel like the right function, but you almost certainly should use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter your data (on your examples link above, it says "See also: loc" in a big yellow box). For this simple example, you could also use boolean indexing:

```
>>> df1.loc[df1['PHASE'] == 'F']  # or boolean indexing via df1[df1['PHASE'] == 'F']
    landuse_SUB_ID  TYPE   RECD_DATE PHASE LAND_USE  CPACTIONDA
3               34     1  2000-04-14     F      REC  2000-04-14
4               34     1  2000-04-14     F      SFD  2000-04-14
10              53     1  2000-02-22     F      SFD  2000-02-22
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did see this solution in other posts. But I initially searched for "filter" method and just want to make it work. And for this method, can I use iloc to achieve the same thing? And a separate question, I'm not sure how to use like and regex in filter either. Does `like = ABC` filter rows with value of just `ABC` or contain `ABC`? And does `regex = 'e$'` mean filtering the rows ending in `e`? Thanks again.

Comment: `iloc` is for indexing by the column number, starting at zero. So you could use boolean indexing with iloc via `df1[df1.iloc[:, 3] == 'F']`.

Comment: Technically you can also do `df1.iloc[(df1['PHASE'] == 'F').values]`,  `iloc` has a few subtle but rarely used features.

Comment: Oh, I thought the only difference between loc and iloc is that iloc can use numbers instead of spelling out column name like with loc. These two filtering methods that you showed are slightly different. I am still very very new to this. Can I understand `df1[df1.iloc[:, 3] == 'F']` as `dataframe[slice criteria]'? Then why can `df1.loc` be followed by a `[slice criteria]`? Thanks. I'm sorry to have bombarded you with questions,

Comment: @jpp thanks. What does `.value` do in your code? My only purpose of using iloc is that I can use number to slice the columns instead of spelling it out. But this seems even a little more laborious than loc. Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu, Extracts NumPy array from a series, see [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.values.html).

Comment: @jpp thanks a lot. You've been very helpful. Could you also help me answer the question I asked Alexander about using `like` and `regex` while filtering please? I'd love to try it out, but the mentioned Error keeps popping up.

Comment: @BowenLiu: I added an example that uses `regex` below in my answer. let me know whether that answers your question.