# how to select rows which one of its columns values contains specific string in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*how to select rows which one of its columns values contains specific string in python?*

I have used the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975069/how-to-filter-rows-containing-a-string-pattern-from-a-pandas-dataframe/27975191) and got errors while I used sample data frame and it looks fine, I am suspicious about my own dataframe which I am reading from a file but still can't guess what the issue is :

```
df=pd.read_csv("location",encoding = "ISO-8859-1") # readCSV
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains('+')
```

***errors:***

> ```
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 616, in _parse
> source.tell() - here + len(this))
> error: nothing to repeat
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` is special regex char (match one or more repetitions), so need escape it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DESCRIPTION': ['aa+','a','+']})

df = df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains('\+')]
print(df)

  DESCRIPTION
0         aa+
2           +
```

Or add parameter `regex=False`:

```
df[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains('+', regex=False)]
```