# How to Remove cells in dataframe with no number in it in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*how to remove cells in dataframe with no number in it in python ?*

I am trying to remove cells from my DataFarme which contains only characters

[image]

I want to remove cells like Farnet and make it null.

actually I check some links such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457744/how-to-select-rows-which-one-of-its-columns-values-contains-specific-string-in-p)  but it didn't answer my question as i want to manipulate cells

Comment: So row with `E2151 A Farnet T3886` is dropped, because `A` and because `Farnet` ?

Comment: I guess OP wants only these two cells be blank or replaced with None

Comment: Kindly post samples in code tags as text not in form of image @f.a

Comment: yes @Rahul your statement is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:['a','DT8510','AFT1',np.nan],
                   1:['a','DT8510','u','as1']})
print (df)
        0       1
0       a       a
1  DT8510  DT8510
2    AFT1       u
3     NaN     as1

import re

d = re.compile('\d')
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if d.search(str(x)) else np.nan)
print (df)
        0       1
0     NaN     NaN
1  DT8510  DT8510
2    AFT1     NaN
3     NaN     as1
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.contains('\d')))
```

Comment: thanks alot,your solution did work, but can you please explain it more and also help me to remove the one which only has less than 4 number in it as well?

Comment: @f.a - so removed `'AFT1'` because only one number ?

Comment: @f.a - then change `\d` to `\d{4}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, one more question, actually I am trying to extract pattern like below : T1370 , a string which start with B,H,N,T,E and have four number afterwards and omit anything coming after or before it and extract as many can be extracted in one cell.

Comment: @f.a - use `'^[BHNTE]{1}\d{4}$'`

Comment: thanks The case is that it'll remove the first cells UH1744 totaly but I would like to only remove U from this string beside I want to make E1780T8126 seprated not remove them totaly.

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution to @jezrael

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':['1','textonly'],'B':['textandnum2','2']})
for column in df.columns:
    df[column][~df[column].str.contains('([1-9])')] = np.nan
df
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use regex for finding the cells which do not have number.

^([^0-9]*)$ expression will find all the cells without numbers.

```
df = df.replace(r'^([^0-9]*)$', np.nan, regex=True)
```

This will replace all the cells with numbers with NaN and then you can use dropna to remove cells.

```
df = df.dropna()
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: seems the output of `df.replace` is not a `dataFrame`  since non of below codes is working and I recive below `error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dropna'` and this is also not working  `df.to_csv("s1.csv",  sep=',')`

Comment: Now you can try it. It should work. I have updated the regex and removed inplace=True.