# How to extract a row which a column which having version number with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a below file, How to extract the row which is having 5.6 version number. I need to find the regex pattern

```
A   KB           1024               MYsql root
B   GB            1                 ELK-6
C   KB           1024               Mysql5.6
E   KB           1024               ELK
F   GB           1                  Mysql5.6
```

Expected Out

```
C   KB           1024               Mysql5.6
F   GB           1                  Mysql5.6
```

My Code in pandas

```
import re
infile = r'C:\user\Desktop\m.txt'
df_list = []
with open(infile) as f:
    for line in f:
        # remove whitespace at the start and the newline at the end
        line = line.strip()
        # split each column on whitespace
        columns = re.split('\s+', line, maxsplit=4)
        df_list.append(columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
df[df[3].str.contains("5.6")]
```

I need to do with regex with Python not with Pandas dataframe. i didnt tag pandas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter rows containing a string pattern from a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975069/how-to-filter-rows-containing-a-string-pattern-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: not with pandas, with regex, with pandas i have wrote the code

Comment: Is your input a long string then?

Comment: No, its not long string

Comment: `pandas.Series.str.contains` already assumes its `pat` as _regex_, which means that your code in pandas is already utilizing regex. Try adding row with `Mysql root == Mysql5A6` and `str.contains("5.6")` will still catch it since `.` is automatically understood as regex.

Comment: I need for regex format. not with pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not, unfortunately, up on pandas, but:

`re.search(r'5\.6', s)`

will return a `match object`, which evaluates to `True`, if the string '5.6' exists anywhere in string `s` or `None`, which evaluates to `False`, if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This [regex](https://regex101.com/r/bl4jRP/1) will match all string with 5.6 version.

```
^.*5\.6$
```