# Create new df with for loop in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, substring

Not sure if I am doing this right - first post here so please be gentle :)

Se below picture.

[Print screen from my Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r04FE.png)

What I am trying to do is to create a new dataframe from the df_Grundinladdning['Datan'] dataframe which *only* include the rows that contain the string "#TRANS".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Datan": ["x", "TRANS y", "z", "TRANS u", "v", "TRANS w"]})
print(df)

new_df = df[df.Datan.str.contains("TRANS")]
print(new_df)
```

Results:

```
(original dataframe)
     Datan
0        x
1  TRANS y
2        z
3  TRANS u
4        v
5  TRANS w

(new dataframe)
     Datan
1  TRANS y
3  TRANS u
5  TRANS w
```

Answer (score 0):

The right method is described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975069/how-to-filter-rows-containing-a-string-pattern-from-a-pandas-dataframe) The loop, even if it did not have syntax errors, would be very very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over the dataframe you can get the result dataframe easily with this:

```
df_transOnly= df_Grundinladdning[df_Grundinladdning["Datan"].str.contains('#TRANS')]
df_transOnly #for printing df
```

So you will get the needed dataframe like this:

```
      Datan
5     #TRANS232
12    #TRANS455
20    #TRANS3144
104   #TRANS1234
500   #TRANS213
```