# Filtering dataframe based on items present in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to filter from a dataframe if search item in found in column (e.g. identifying all employees-empID with the searched expertise area

```
import pandas as pd
date=[
      [123,['abc','def','efg']],
      [124,['abc','qwe','mno']],
      [124,['abc','qwe','mno']],
      [126,['wer','abc']]
     ]
expertise_df=pd.DataFrame(date,columns=['EmpId','areas'])
```

I am looking to filter for rows that have 'abc' or 'qwe' etc- but without explicitly creating loops across all rows and checking for match. I tried the expertise_df['areas'.str.contains but that doesn't return results. This will be matching around 1000 search strings on 200,000 rows in the expertise_df and hence looking for time-efficient approaches. The brute-force approach takes over 4 hours and not practical

Also, if I need to create union operations (contains either 'abc' or 'pqr' etc)- is there a way the results could be handled as sets to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check for multiple values (`['def', 'wer']` for example), you could use the negation of [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with [isdisjoint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint).

```
mask = ~expertise_df['areas'].apply(frozenset(['def', 'wer']).isdisjoint)
res = expertise_df[mask]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   EmpId            areas
0    123  [abc, def, efg]
3    126       [wer, abc]
```

Comment: Nice answer, simpler than mine.

Answer (score 2):

To filter for rows which contain `qwe` as a list element in second column of `expertise_df`, can do:

```
expertise_df[
    pd.DataFrame(
        expertise_df.explode('areas')\
        ['areas'].str.contains('qwe'))\
    .reset_index()\
    .groupby('index')\
    .any()['areas']]
```

This will give you:

```
   EmpId            areas
1    124  [abc, qwe, mno]
2    124  [abc, qwe, mno]
```

If want to find rows which contain either element of a list, ie:

```
searchfor = ['wer','def']
```

then do, using [How to filter rows containing a string pattern from a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975069/how-to-filter-rows-containing-a-string-pattern-from-a-pandas-dataframe):

```
expertise_df[
    pd.DataFrame(
        expertise_df.explode('areas')\
        ['areas'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor)))\
    .reset_index()\
    .groupby('index')\
    .any()['areas']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set intersection to filter the rows you want.

```
import pandas as pd
date=[
      [123,['abc','def','efg']],
      [124,['abc','qwe','mno']],
      [124,['abc','qwe','mno']],
      [126,['wer','abc']]
     ]
expertise_df=pd.DataFrame(date,columns = ['EmpId','areas'])

filter_set = {'def','wer'}
filtered_df=expertise_df[expertise_df['areas'].
    apply(lambda el: bool(filter_set.intersection(el)))]

print(filtered_df)
```

Output:

```
EmpId            areas
0    123  [abc, def, efg]
3    126       [wer, abc]
```