# Selecting rows based on value pandas

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to select only the row that consist the value Morning

```
ID 16615 Morning, Morning, Night, Evening
ID 16617 Night, Night, Night, Night
ID 16618 Evening, Morning
ID 16619 Evening, Night, Morning, Morning
ID 16620 Evening, Evening, Evening, Afternoon
ID 166621 Afternoon, Afternoon, Afternoon, Morning
```

Output

```
ID 16615 Morning, Morning, Night, Evening
ID 16618 Evening, Morning
ID 16619 Evening, Night, Morning, Morning
ID 166621 Afternoon, Afternoon, Afternoon, Morning
```

Meaning to only select rows that consist 'Morning'

Comment: df[df.str.contains('Morning')]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter rows containing a string pattern from a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975069/how-to-filter-rows-containing-a-string-pattern-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: It returns to this. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'. i checked dtypes it returns objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check in all columns then you can try:

```
df = df.loc[df.astype(str).apply(' '.join,1).str.contains('Morning')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df[df.str.contains('Morning', regex=False)]
```

Meaning from your DataFrame (df) select only df's rows that contain the word `'Morning'` without implement it in regex query.